# Chrome API - detect tab with user input

Tags: api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I've noticed instinctively that with too many tabs open, Chrome tends to prioritze suspending those WITHOUT user inputted data -- like form fields, composing a message, writing a comment, etc., to save on RAM.

1. Is this true?
2. And is there a way to detect which tabs have user inputted data via the Chrome Extension API?

Thanks :)

Comment: 1) Sounds plausible. 2) There's no API for this but you can use a content script with standard DOM listeners e.g. for `input` event to detect user input. 3) If you additionally use a [port connection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#connect) then theoretically the background script will receive an onDisconnect event when the tab is hibernated/discarded.